# How to Block direct access to url and allowing access only by application in IIS?

Tags: iis, block

How to block direct access to url and allowing access by application in IIS?
Here's an example:
in this image application allowing access to file but direct access to url is blocked.

access file by application preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/emNdy.jpg
url:https://www.farayad.org/video/play/farayad/2700/178e27d09e44eb1becc8003e497dcec8c2b10916/720p.mp4/seg-22-v1-a1.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use "request filtering" and use the Deny URL Sequences tab to create a list of URL sequences for which the request-filtering module will deny access(in the "URL" tab).

More information you can refer to this link: [URL Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831518(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#url-tab).

Comment: after configure for "URL Tab" in request filtering , application cannot access to file,this is my code:   <source src="Video/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">   and Deny URL Sequences is "video/mov_bbb.mp4 "

Comment: Do you get any errors when the application cannot access the file?

Comment: Yes, 404 Not Found

Comment: Can you show me the detailed error message of 404 Not Found？